# I want to make my web site point to different server dynamically

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I'm new to web.config and ASP.NEt. I want to make my client to point to different servers which ever is free dynamically....

Is it possible???

It's their a  way to have multiple entries in web.config file which we can choose at run time???

Let me be more specific. I have multiple clients which contacts a server for the resource but due to excess load on server I want to have multiple server and which ever server is free that client should contact that server.

Thanks for the Help in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a separate load balancer in front of your servers.

Also, if you need application sessions, then you will need to move application state out of process - to SQL Server or to ASP.NET State Service, so different servers will share the session state.

You can read about your options about sharing session between servers here: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1049585.html

Answer (score 1):

Redirect might work for you:

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_redirect.asp

Also you could try using a proxy server:

http://www.iisproxy.net/

or load balancing server:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gopenath/Page107182007032219AM/Page1.aspx

Comment: Redirect's not an option here - we want to load balance servers, not use some resources on one to make hop to another. Proxy server would be a single point of failure and a bottleneck. Load balancer is what you seek :)